# Social IBM App ID login without default App ID login widget

Tags: javascript, ibm-cloud, google-signin, app-id, ibm-appid

I'm required to implement login using google/facebook from clients own front end application using **IBM App ID** service. Meaning login widget that is provided by IBM **must never show**.

Front end is developed using react js and back-end is separate node-js server. I figured how to bypass widget for cloud directory login but i have no luck for social login. If i just copy form code for google login provided by default IBM app id login widget (copied code is as follows)

```
<form
  action="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"
  method="get"
  id="google_form"
  aria-label="google_form"
>
  <input
      type="hidden"
      name="client_id"
      value="526589484289-sth1s4he8en575sugh6rain3hh054p97.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      id="google_client_id"
  ></input>
  <input
      type="hidden"
      name="redirect_uri"
      value="https://eu-uk.appid.cloud.ibm.com/oauth/v4/DEFAULT-GOOGLE-TENANT-ID/Google/callback"
      id="google_redirect_uri"
  ></input>
  <input type="hidden" name="response_type" value="code"></input>
  <input
      type="hidden"
      name="scope"
      id="google_scope"
      value="email profile"
  ></input>
  <input
      type="hidden"
      name="state"
      value="woU6LcOCwrTDr8OXw63DnQNAwr5xdinCtxcKJsKKYcKWX8OGw5zCoh0Fw4k"
      id="google_state"
  ></input>
  <button
      type="submit"

      id="google_login"
  >
      <div>Login with Google</div>
  </button>
</form>
```

Sometimes I get the following (it worked few times but redirect was to backend "/" route for some reason)

```
{
"error_code": "GENERAL_ERROR",
"error_description": "key not found"
}
```

Question is how do i implement social login with custom UI and what do i have to send to passport in order to login, get token and user data. And how to redirect with that data to front-end server. (Front end is on seperate server and communication with backend is REST so token must be sent with each request)

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days without any luck so any help would be greatly appreciated. I'd appreciate code example showing how to login using google or facebook from custom fronted to nodejs backend using IBM App ID but any help at all would help.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have FB, Google, and Cloud Directory logins without showing the widget, you will need 3 different App ID instances. Each one configured to only have one identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the other Identity Providers disabled in App ID, then you should be forwarded directly to google authentication. That way the login widget of App ID should not be shown.

Comment: What if i want to have facebook and google and cloud directory logins and still not have widget?

Comment: Like @jhuang3 answered, in that case you need to have one App ID instance per integration.